# Chunk an array with custom size for some index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array-like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and I want to split this array into groups so I write:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'chunk_inefficient', {
  value: function(chunkSize) {
    var array = this;
    return [].concat.apply([],
      array.map(function(elem, i) {
        return i % chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i, i + chunkSize)];
      })
    );
  }
});
```

Using   `var pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].chunk_inefficient(3);` I got arrays like:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]; and all its ok.
```

How I can update my function to keep creating arrays like this but etc. 2nd array to create with 2 elements;

```
var choose_array = 2;
var choose_elements_in_array = 2;
```

based om this 2 variables I need to change 2nd array to contain only 2 elements so I need to get array like:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8], [9,10]];
```

if

```
 var choose_array = 1;
    var choose_elements_in_array = 2;
```

then array needs to be like:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10]];
```

If it easier how to recreate array `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]];` to `[[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10]];` based on my variables

```
var choose_array = 1;
        var choose_elements_in_array = 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an additional `rules` object which has the custom chunk size for each index in the output. If it is not defined for that index, use the default chunk size:

```js
function conditionalChunk(array, size, rules = {}) {
  let copy = [...array],
      output = [],
      i = 0;

  while (copy.length)
    output.push( copy.splice(0, rules[i++] ?? size) )

  return output
}
```

For the below `rules` object

```
{
   0: 4,
   1: 2
}
```

The output will be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
function conditionalChunk(array, size, rules = {}) {
  let copy = [...array],
      output = [],
      i = 0;

  while (copy.length)
    output.push( copy.splice(0, rules[i++] ?? size) )

  return output
}

console.log(  
  JSON.stringify( conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3, { 1: 2 }) ) 
)

console.log(
  JSON.stringify( conditionalChunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3, { 0:4, 1:2 }) )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works very well. Please just a suggestion - WHat is I have an array like: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]; and I just want to change 2 arrays to contain 2 products?

Comment: @AleksPer are you always going to reduce the number of items in the array? Like, you only want to make it `2` and not `4`.

Comment: no, sometimes I want to reduce to 2 elements, sometimes I need 4

Comment: @AleksPer the simplest way is to call the above `conditionalChunk` with `array.flat()` as input array

Comment: Sorry for boring you but what if I have an input array like: [{'page_layout': 1, 'theme': 0, 'items', [1,2,3]}, {'page_layout': 5, 'theme': 1, 'items', [4,5,6,7]}]
... because chunk is actually pages and I need to put more details before each chunk

Comment: @AleksPer what is the expected output?

Comment: expected output keep object with the same data just move 'items' elements between

Comment: @AleksPer `input.flatMap(a => a.items)` gets you a flat array if items. You could chunk that using the function above. Assign each chunk to each object's items based on the index?

Comment: ok, but please write how to assign items based on index

Comment: @AleksPer use a `for` loop: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/euorzytb/